# Python Scraper for Links

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
data = requests.get("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2014_games.html")    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)    
soup.find_all("a")    
for link in soup.find_all("a"):    
    "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href=/boxscores"),link.text)
```

I am trying to get the links for the box scores only. Then run a loop and organize the data from the individual links into a csv. I need to save the links as vectors and run a loop....then I am stuck and I am not sure if this is even the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over all links that have `href` attribute (`a[href]` [CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)), then loop over the links and [construct an absolute link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) if `href` attribute value doesn't start with `http`. Collect all links into a list of lists and use [`writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) to dump it to csv:

```
import csv
from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


base_url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com'
data = requests.get("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2014_games.html")    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)    

links = [[urljoin(base_url, link['href']) if not link['href'].startswith('http') else link['href']]
         for link in soup.select("a[href]")]

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(links)
```

`output.csv` now contains:

```
http://www.sports-reference.com
http://www.baseball-reference.com
http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/
http://www.pro-football-reference.com
http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/
http://www.hockey-reference.com/
http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/
http://www.sports-reference.com/blog/
http://www.sports-reference.com/feedback/
http://www.basketball-reference.com/my/auth.cgi
http://twitter.com/bball_ref
...
```

It is unclear what your output should be, but this is, at least, what you can use a starting point.